# How do I achieve thread safety in following code

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm reading about thread safety and `synchronized` keyword, but I'm stuck figuring out how it's implemented correctly.

I have a scenario where `Thread` **A** saves data to a `Buffer` while `Thread` **B** reads the data and saves it to the database.

How can I achieve thread safety with the following code?
By thread safety I mean `Thread` B wont start until `Thread` A finished it's job and same applies to `Thread` A.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        LinkedBlockingQueue<Document> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        ProducerThread mProducer = new ProducerThread(queue);
        ConsumerThread mConsumer = new ConsumerThread(queue);
        new Thread(mProducer).start();
        new Thread(mConsumer).start();
    }
}
```

--

```
public class ProducerThread implements Runnable {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Document> queue;

    public ProducerThread(LinkedBlockingQueue<Document> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Document document = new Document("timeAdded", timestamp);
            try {
                queue.put(document);
                System.out.println("Document added " + document.toString());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
public class ConsumerThread implements Runnable {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Document> queue;
    private Database mDatabase;

    public ConsumerThread(LinkedBlockingQueue<Document> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
            try {
                Document doc;
                mDatabase = Database.getInstance();
                if (Client.isAlive()) {
                    while (queue.take() != null) {
                        mDatabase.insert(queue.take());
//                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        System.out.println("Document consumed " + queue.take().toString());
                        if (!Client.isAlive()) {
                            wait();
                            Client.reconnect();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    wait();
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException | IllegalMonitorStateException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

I get the following output

```
> Document added{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:27.88}} 
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:27.88}} Document added
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:28.881}} Document added
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:29.882}} Document added
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:30.882}} Consumed
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:30.882}} Document added
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:31.883}} Document added
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:32.883}} Consumed
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:33.884}} Document added
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:33.884}} Document added
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:34.885}} Document added
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:35.885}} Document added
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:36.886}} Consumed
> Document{{timeAdded=2018-04-22 13:20:36.886}} Document added
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please create a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Turing85 sorry , i updated the question

Comment: I you want thread B to start when thread A is done, why do you even need multiple threads? That sounds like work that you can do on a single thread.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thread A saves data to buffer, thread b reads the data and stores it to database, if the server is offline thread A continues to store the data to buffer, when a connection with the server is enabled thread B will store the data to database

Comment: Then your phrasing of _"Thread B wont start until Thread A finished it's job_" is off, because thread A won't have finished its job.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry i meant when Thread A finishes putting a object inside the buffer then Thread B should start reading from the buffer while Thread A waits till it read that object

Comment: If you use queue object reference from your `Main` class that you pass as argument to `consumer` and `producer` classes and do not initiate a local reference to the same object , you can put your operations on the queue in a `synchronized(queue){}` block within both producer and consumer threads, which i believe can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps, but I would write a third class called *ProductionProcess* or something like that...

Short additional explanation: The *ProductionClass* holds the queue which stores the single *Document* objects. The *Producer* thread starts to "produce" objects as long as the queue (At the moment size of 10) is full. Whenever a slot in this queue gets free because the *Consumer* thread removed a *Document* object. The *Producer* thread receives a signal and starts "producing" *Document* objects again until the queue is full. The complete source code should be thread-safe.

```
public class ProductionProcess
{
private static final int CAPACITY;
private final Queue QUEUE;

private final Lock LOCK;
private final Condition BUFFER_FULL;
private final Condition BUFFER_EMPTY;

static
{
    CAPACITY = 10;
}

ProductionProcess()
{
    this.QUEUE = new LinkedList <Document> ();
    this.LOCK = new ReentrantLock();

    this.BUFFER_FULL = this.LOCK.newCondition();
    this.BUFFER_EMPTY = this.LOCK.newCondition();
}

public void produce() throws InterruptedException
{
    this.LOCK.lock();

    try
    {
        while(ProductionProcess.CAPACITY == this.QUEUE.size())
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : Buffer is full, waiting!");
            this.BUFFER_FULL.await();
        }

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Document document = new Document("timeAdded", timestamp);

        if(true == this.QUEUE.offer(document))
        {
            System.out.printf("Added to queue: " + document);
            this.BUFFER_EMPTY.signalAll();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this.LOCK.unlock();
    }
}

public void receive() throws InterruptedException
{
    this.LOCK.lock();

    try
    {
        Database mDatabase = Database.getInstance();

        while(0 == this.QUEUE.size())
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : Buffer is empty, waiting!");
            this.BUFFER_EMPTY.await();
        }

        Document mDocument = (Document) this.QUEUE.poll());

        if(null != mDocument)
        {
            mDatabase.insert(mDocument);
            System.out.printf("Consumed from queue: " + document);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : Signalling that buffer may be empty now");
            this.BUFFER_FULL.signalAll();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this.LOCK.unlock();
    }
}
}
```

After that use it like this...

```
ProductionProcess process = new ProductionProcess();

Runnable runnableProducer = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
        try
        {
            process.produce();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
}

Runnable runnableConsumer = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
        try
        {
            process.receive();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
}

new Thread(runnableProducer).start();
new Thread(runnableConsumer).start();
```

I don't test it extensive but it should work. If it doesn't work just comment it...
Moreover its not my code if you can speak german watch this [link](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/java7/1507_02_005.html#dodtpb14d2a0a-be01-422b-b9ce-372b09ef8491).